# how can I receive external display connection notification in launchd?

Tags: macos, display, launchd

How does one receive notification from `notifyd` (or equiv) when the display configuration changes? My goal is to fire off some daemons when connected to my thunderbolt display "dock". Any example scripts gratefully accepted.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help, but if any files in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/ are changed when a monitor is attached, then you could use a script to check for display configuration changes. I have done something like that at <https://github.com/tjluoma/onnetworkchange> for dealing with network changes, but I am not sure if the same thing would work for display changes.

Comment: @TJLuoma I don't see any changes in SystemConfiguration/.  I see log entries in /var/log/system.log, but that's it.